# Problema con el método de ordenación QuickSort

Tags: java, ordenamiento, quicksort

El ejercicio me pide que, con el método QuickSort, si el programa ha podido ordenar el array, me devuelva un 1, si ya estaba ordenado, me devuelva un 0 y si no se ha podido ordenar, que me devuelva un numero negativo, el -1 por ejemplo.

He conseguido que me devuelva bien el 1 y el 0, pero no consigo que me devuelva el -1.

Aquí dejo el código:

**El main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vector = {5, 2, 1, 9, 3, 8, 7};
    //int[] vector = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; Este array lo uso para comprobar si me devuelve bien el 0
    
    System.out.println("Este es el vector que va a ser ordenado:");
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(vector[i] + " ");
    }
    
    int izq = 0;
    int der = (vector.length - 1);
    
    System.out.println("\n\nEl pivote escogido es:\n" + vector[0]);
    
    System.out.print("\nResultado: " + ordenarQuickSort(vector, izq, der));
}
```

**El método:**

```
static int ordenarQuickSort(int[] vector, int izq, int der) {
    int pivote = vector[izq];
    int i = izq;
    int j = der;
    int aux;
    
    int vectorOrdenado = 0;
    
    while (i < j) {
        while (vector[i] <= pivote && i < j) {
            i++;
        }
        
        while (vector[j] > pivote) {
            j--;
        }
        
        if (i < j) {
            aux = vector[i];
            vector[i] = vector[j];
            vector[j] = aux;
            vectorOrdenado = 1;
        }
    }
        
    vector[izq] = vector[j];
    vector[j] = pivote;
    
    return vectorOrdenado;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo devolvería -1? Es decir, cuándo crees que no podría ordenar el arreglo? Y dónde está ese escenario implementado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te han mencionado no existe un escenario donde te devuelva -1,entonces por que no  declarar

```
int vectorOrdenado = -1;
```

Al hacerlo:

-Para obtener 0 (si el arreglo esta ordenado) se debe condicionar antes de aplicar el algoritmo **quickSort**

-Para obtener 1 (si el arreglo se puede ordenar) como esto si ah de ser posible en cada caso en que los elemento del array sean numéricos, se debe condicionar luego de aplicar el algoritmo **quickSort**

-Para obtener -1(en caso no se pueda) se quedaría con el valor default con el que se inicializo, al no cumplir las condiciones antes mencionadas

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main{
  public static int ordenarQuickSort(int vector[], int izq, int der) {

  int pivote=vector[izq]; // tomamos primer elemento como pivote
  int i=izq;         // i realiza la búsqueda de izquierda a derecha
  int j=der;         // j realiza la búsqueda de derecha a izquierda
  int aux;

  //Si no se pudiera ordenar el valor de vectorOrdenado por default sera de -1
    int vectorOrdenado = -1;

    boolean sorted = true; 
    for(int k = 1; k < vector.length; k++) {
      if(vector[k-1] > vector[k]){
         sorted = false;
        break; 
      } 
    } 
    
    if(sorted){vectorOrdenado=0;}//comprobamos que el arreglo dado este ordenado

  //inicio del quickSort
 
  while(i < j){                          // mientras no se crucen las búsquedas                                   
     while(vector[i] <= pivote && i < j) i++; // busca elemento mayor que pivote
     while(vector[j] > pivote) j--;           // busca elemento menor que pivote
     if (i < j) {                        // si no se han cruzado                      
         aux= vector[i];                      // los intercambia
         vector[i]=vector[j];
         vector[j]=aux;
     }
   }
   
   vector[izq]=vector[j];      // se coloca el pivote en su lugar de forma que tendremos                                    
   vector[j]=pivote;      // los menores a su izquierda y los mayores a su derecha
   
   if(izq < j-1)
      ordenarQuickSort(vector,izq,j-1);          // ordenamos subarray izquierdo
   if(j+1 < der)
      ordenarQuickSort(vector,j+1,der);          // ordenamos subarray derecho


  //fin del quickSort
  
  if(vectorOrdenado!=0){// al usar el algoritmo quickSort el array estara ordenado por ende usamos una condicional
    //para obviar el 0 en caso el array como parametro este ordenado
   sorted=true;  
   for(int k = 1; k < vector.length; k++) {
      if(vector[k-1] > vector[k]){
         sorted = false;
        break; 
      } 
    } 
     if(sorted){vectorOrdenado=1;}
     //en caso el arreglo no este ordenado,luego de usar el quick sort lo estara, por ende 
     //le asignamos 1

    }
  return vectorOrdenado;
   
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] persa={10,5,6,7,9,2,3};
    int [] persa2={1,2,3,5,6,7,9};

    //desordenado pero si se puede ordenar
    System.out.println(ordenarQuickSort(persa,0,(persa.length-1)));
    //ordenado
    System.out.println(ordenarQuickSort(persa2,0,(persa2.length-1)));
  
}
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Dramaturgo